# Создание связи при добавлении в таблицу UPD

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте.
Есть три таблицы (две с данными и одна для связи многие-к-многим):

```
users:       id, name, email (уникален);

groups:      id, title;

group_users: id_user, id_group;
```

В таблицу users добавляются данные, из файла или из другой таблицы. Для всех новых записей добавляются связи к одной новой группе. В данных возможны записи с email уже имеющимися в таблице users. В этом случае необходимо только добавление новой связи старой записи к новой группе.

Возможно ли это реализовать средствами MySQL? Если да, то как изящнее это реализовать? Спасибо.

UPD:

Имеется N-ное количество новых пользователей, их всех надо добавить в Одну Новую группу.
Если пользователь уже имеется (проверяется по email), то уже имеющегося пользователя добавить в новую группу, ту же куда и новых пользователей.

title групп не уникален, хотя это и не важно.

Т.с. подвопрос: возможно ли одним запросом провести вставку в таблицу со связью (не заморачиваясь пока что на дубликаты)?

Comment: update не подходит?

Comment: Т.е. новые users.name и users.id теряются? или какие данные поступают при добавлении новых записей?

Comment: Не совсем понятны бизнес-правила: один и тот же пользователь может входить в несколько групп?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, при импорте пользователей для каждого пользователя создаётся группа, через которую потом раздаётся доступ. Т.е. перед вставкой нового пользователя вставляется новая группа. Пусть вставляется, мы сохраняем её id.

При добавлении новой записи в `users` нужно обработать исключение БД, которое создаст UNIQUE constraint по e-mail. Когда оно получено, ничего не делать (пользователь уже есть), но сразу после этого выполнить update group_users для пользователя по этому e-mail, чтобы добавить его в новую группу.

Вроде, так. :-)

Comment: Чудесно. ТС спросил "как изящнее" и народ начинает фантазировать. А нет бы топик-стартёру объяснить поконкретнее. Т.е. если на входе кортеж: (имя-пользователя, титул, e-mail), то так. Для нового пользователя создаются записи в users, groups, group_users. Если e-mail уже есть, то запись в users пропускается (имя отбрасываетя?). groups.title уникален или нет? И т.д. Но это, по-видимому весьма конфиденциальная информация...

Comment: @alexlz, Бог мой, вы предлагаете сначала мучать базу запросом на наличие пользователя, а потом добавлять или нет? Лучше бы сами не фантазировали. Я написал как раз конкретно, что нужно сделать. Или я должен был реализацию запилить? :-)

Comment: @orkaan я ничего не предлагаю. Я просто фиксирую, что задача непонятна, и желательно эти моменты прояснить, прежде чем ждать разумных советов

Да, кстати, у Вас база -- она что, царапается или кусается, если её начинают мучить? Страшное дело.

Comment: @alexlz, не стоит делать запрос, прежде чем сделать модификации. Это лишние накладные расходы на довольно таки простой бизнес-процесс.

Comment: @orkaan Уговорили. Не буду делать никаких запросов. Я с большим вниманием выслушиваю/читаю советы истинно верующих.